# Jar-File runs in console, but crahes when executed by batch-file

Tags: java, eclipse, batch-file, jar

My programm uses a lot of memory, because it has to read huge .xls -Files.
So I added in Eclipse the argument -Xms512 and that works well for me.
The exported jar-file works the same when I run it from the commandline:

```
java -jar -Xms512 Excel_to_csv.jar
```

But when I run it with a .bat-file it runs, but crashes because of memory-problems:

```
java -jar -Xms512m Excel_to_csv.jar
```

I appreciate any ideas.

Comment: This is strange. Have you tried to start your bat as administrator?

Comment: My company unfortunately doesn´t allow that. So I can´t test it with Launch4j, my favorit solution.

Comment: OK but you know your own credentials. Try to SHIFT+Rightclick on the file, select "Run as a different user" and enter your account data. Tell me if this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix the order of arguments: `-jar` expects the file name as argument but you give it `-Xms`. And saying "MB" probably is a good idea as well:

```
java -Xms512m -jar Excel_to_csv.jar
```

I'm not sure what the default is when you just say `512` but my guess would be KiB (meaning 512 KiB of RAM) which wouldn't be enough to even start the process.

That said, `ms` just sets the *start* amount of memory Java gets. If you process a complex Excel, you may need more memory. Try with

```
java -Xms512m -Xmx2000m -jar Excel_to_csv.jar
```

to allow Java to allocate as much as 2000 MiB when it has to.

Comment: Your stuff works as well as mine in the command-line (I think the order doesn´t matter here), but it doesn´t help the bat-file. I have tried all variations.

Comment: Use `jconsole` to attach to the running process and check the memory settings (are they what you'd expect?) plus watch how much memory the process needs.

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea but I'm not sure. To use `Xms` parameter the user which is running the command must have the permission to **lock pages in memory**. Usually this right is granted to your user account. When you runc the command in command line it is running under your user account and everything works fine. When you pack the command into a batch file and start it, it is running under the account "SYSTEM". Now it's possible that this account doesn't have this permission (not sure about this point). To fix this do the following:

1. On the Start menu, click Run. In the Open box, type gpedit.msc.
2. On the Local Group Policy Editor console, expand Computer Configuration, and then expand Windows Settings.
3. Expand Security Settings, and then expand Local Policies.
4. Select the User Rights Assignment folder. The policies will be displayed in the details pane
5. In the pane, double-click Lock pages in memory.
6. In the Local Security Setting – Lock pages in memory dialog box, click Add User or Group.
7. In the Select Users, Service Accounts, or Groups dialog box, add the account "SYSTEM".
8. Log out and then log back in for this change to take effect.

*taken (and modified) from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190730.aspx*

Comment: Unfortunately I can´t do that because I have no permission to run gpedit.msc but maybe it helps someone else ;)

Comment: Have you tried my comment?
 
"OK but you know your own credentials. Try to SHIFT+Rightclick on the file, select "Run as a different user" and enter your account data."

Comment: I have no option "Run as a different user" , I can just run as administrator and choose there "Run as a different user", but again it says you have no permission.

Comment: Strange. When I SHIFT+right-click on a file, I get this: http://de.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2441rw8&s=8#.VS-aU5NvFTs. Yre you sure that you've pressed SHIFT?

Comment: I am sorry, I found it now (couldn´t change my comment...)but i doesnt work. I have found now a solution: When I use .cmd instead of .bat it magically works. But I will investigate this further (Because this can not be).

Comment: I really dont know, why exactly it didn´t work but now it seems to work with the .bat-file. I can only guess it has something to do with my network-drive.